# Dynamic router and page with Next.js and Prisma

Tags: javascript, database, next.js, prisma

I have cards with product information in my database, I display them successfully on the user's page. Now I want to add a more details button on each card to go to a new page from it (/pages/card/[id]). But I don't really understand how I can pull out the card value by clicking through my API.

```
 const res = await fetch('/api/cards/' + id, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id: id })
    })
    if (res.ok) {
        const result = await (await res).json()
        if (result.redirectUrl) {
           router.push(result.redirectUrl as string)
        }
      }
    }
```

API

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { id } = req.query
        if (req.method === 'GET') {
            if (typeof id === 'string') {
                const moreDetail= await db.sales.findUnique({
                    where: { 
                        id: id },
                })
                 res.send({ redirectUrl: '/card'+[id] }) 
            }
        }
```

My card in schema

```
  id          String   @id @default(cuid())
  title       String
  description String
  active      Boolean  @default(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to introduce another API endpoint that returns an array of all of the available cards, or at least an array of all of the available card ids. After that, create a new page matching your URL format `/pages/card/[id].tsx` and inside that file, create your page like normal, but also export 2 functions:

- [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)
- [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props)

These let Next know what paths are available and how to load data for them during the build process.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const cardIds = await fetch('/api/cards', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });

  return {
    paths: cardIds.map((id) => (
     {
       params: { id }
     },
    )),
    fallback: false, // setting to false will throw a 404 if none match
  };
}
```

This lets Next know all of the available dynamic routes to generate pages for.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { id } }) {
  const card = await fetch(`/api/cards/${id}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });

  return {
    props: {
      card,
    },
  }
}
```

This actually loads the data from your API given a card id and passes it into your component to display more details for.

Hopefully that gives you a good jumping off point.